# How to remove Inverse match pairs?

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, perl

I want to remove duplicate/inverse match pairs from a text file.

E.g., the file contains data like the below:

```
10 |Name1 |20 |Name2
20 |Name2 |30 |Name3
20 |Name2 |10 |Name1   <-- Inverse pair (compared to first line) to be removed from text file
40 |Name4 |30 |Name3
```

I am expecting output like the below:

```
10 |Name1 |20 |Name2
20 |Name2 |30 |Name3
40 |Name4 |30 |Name3
```

Answer (score 3):

with awk:

```
awk -F '[[:blank:]]*[|][[:blank:]]*' -v SUBSEP='|' '
    ($1,$2,$3,$4) in seen || ($3,$4,$1,$2) in seen {next} 
    {seen[$1,$2,$3,$4]; print}
' file
```

That sets the field separator to the pipe character with optional leading or trailing whitespace. Then it looks for the "pairs" as associative array keys, in either order: if found, skip this line; otherwise, add the key to the array and print the line.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like:

```
perl -F'[|]' -lane '
  for (@F) {
    # trim the fields to remove leading and trailing blanks
    s/^\s+//; s/\s+$//
  }
  # re-join the trimmed fields into $a
  my $a = join "|", @F[0..3];

  # same, inverting the two pairs into $b
  my $b = join "|", @F[2,3,0,1];

  # print unless either $a or $b has been seen before
  print unless $seen{$a} || $seen{$b}++' < your-file
```

To generalise to any number of pairs found in any order, you'd want to sort those pairs to make the key of the `%seen` associative array:

```
perl -F'[|]' -lane '
  for (@F) {
    # trim the fields to remove leading and trailing blanks
    s/^\s+//; s/\s+$//
  }

  my @pairs;
  while (my ($a, $b) = splice(@F, 0, 2)) {
    push @pairs, "$a|$b"
  }
  my $key = join "|", sort @pairs;

  print unless $seen{$key}++' < your-file
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with sed. The code below is using gnu sed, but it can readily be made posix compliant.

```
sed -Ee '
   $!{
      s/$/|/
      N
      s/[[:blank:]]+//g
      H;s/.*//;x;D
   }
   s/$/|/
   G;H;g
   y/\n_/_\n/
   :xdup
       s/_((([^_|]+[|]){2})(([^_|]+[|]){2}))_(.*_)?\4\2_/_\1_\6/
   txdup
   s/^_//;s/_$//
   y/\n_/_\n/
'  input.csv
```

Will explain later as rush hour approacht

Results :

```
10|Name1|20|Name2|
20|Name2|30|Name3|
40|Name4|30|Name3|
```